# Amazon AWS - dynamoDB with tornado

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tornado

There is this open source project asyncdynamo

http://word.bitly.com/post/18861837158/introducing-asyncdynamo

https://github.com/bitly/asyncdynamo

But it's outdated, it uses tornado 1.2.1.
I can't test it yet because i don't have a credit card.

.

Is it possible to use tornado with dynamoDB ?*(without asyncdynamo)*

.

If yes , does tornado give me an performance advantage over other server solutions ? *(while using dynamoDB)*

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can always use [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto). It's a third-party library that should work fine with any python program.

For the tornado part, the server's performance has nothing to do with dynamoDB but itself and your code. You can find a detailed benchmark of many python wsgi servers [here](http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers).

Comment: The server's performance IS impacted by using a IO blocking library.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [asyncboto](https://github.com/almost/asyncboto) with Tornado (version 3.1).  It requires some restructuring of your code to utilize callbacks.  Also, you will have to add decorators to allow asynchronous calls in Tornado (see [here](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gen.html) or elsewhere on StackOverflow)